# I need help finding Lucky Patcher's mysterious files

Tags: samsung, internal-storage, lucky-patcher

I am using a Samsung A10s with 32gb of storage, running Android 11 and One UI Core 3.1.

I was fiddling around trying to install a ~700mb game through LP. It says storage not sufficient even though i have  2,6gb of storage left, so i decided to open it through Zarchiver.

My mistake was not realizing it was an .APKS file, not .APK and opening it straight from the data folder (Android/data/LP directory). I clicked install. Realizing i have made a mistake, i closed Zarchiver.

Guess what? I lost 700mb worth of space! I tried looking everywhere for the files, even tried deleting the system trash files but it didn't work. Now i have 1,8gb. Haven't gave up, i tried to reinstall via LP.

This time, it showed an error message "Failed to allocate 7-something (file size) because only 6-something (storage) allocatable". I lost even more space. Now i only have around 1.2gb.

In total, i lost 1,4gb and i couldn't find the culprit.

I need help finding the files because storage is very important for me. Please.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the app SD Maid, the free version should work for you. It can find file duplicates and delete them. This is the only way I know of, so you are gonna need space to download it. It is pretty lightweight though.